# Image download with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to download images with Python 3.9.1
Other than the first 2-3 images, all images are 1 kb in size. How do I download all pictures? Please, help me.
Sample book: http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid=568450&pno=1

```
import urllib.request
import os

bibID = input("ID: ")
first = int(input("First page: "))
last  = int(input("Last page: "))

if not os.path.exists(bibID):
    os.makedirs(bibID)

for i in range(first,last+1):
    url=f"http://web2.anl.az:81/read/img.php?bibid={bibID}&pno={i}"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,f"{bibID}/{i}.jpg")
```

Comment: What is your question? ("help me" is not a question)

Comment: Sorry, man. I am new here. I just want to download all the pictures as. But most pictures are 1 kb in size. Asking how to do.

Comment: What is the problem with that? Maybe they are just 1 kb in size.

Comment: No, they aren't 1 kb in size. Just my code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there is an issue with your script. It has to do with the APIs you are hitting and the sequence required.

A `GET http://web2.anl.az:81/read/img.php?bibid=568450&pno=<page>` just on its own doesn't seem to work right away. Instead, it returns `No FILE HERE`
[image: Screenshot from postman]

The reason this happens is that the retrieval of the images is linked to your `cookie`. You first need to initiate your read session that's generated when first visiting the page and clicking the `TƏSDİQLƏYIRƏM` button

From what I could tell you need to do the following:

1. `POST http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid=568450` with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` body. It should have a single key value of `approve: TƏSDİQLƏYIRƏM` - this starts a session and generates a cookie for you which you have to add as a **header for all of your API calls** from now on.
   E.g.

```
requests.post('http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid=568450', files=dict(approve='TƏSDİQLƏYIRƏM'))
```

2. Do the following in your for-loop of pages:

   a. `GET http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid=568450&pno=<page number>` - page won't show up if you don't do this first

   b. `GET http://web2.anl.az:81/read/img.php?bibid=568450&pno=<page number>` - finally get the image!

Comment: You solved my 1 kb problem. Thank you very much for that.
But I still couldn't solve the "Təsdiqləyirəm" problem.
This button is not available on every links. How can I check if exist? and if there is, then click it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you please give an example/

Comment: 1. http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid=568450&pno=1
2. http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid=vtls000000004